# Why does semi-colon after a macro cause illegal else compile error

Tags: c, macros

Apparently I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how macros work.  I thought a macro just caused the preprocessor to replace the `@define`d macro with the replacement text.  But apparently that's not always the case.  My code follows:
**TstBasInc.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>

//  copy macro
#define Cpy(ToVar, FrmVar) do {                                                                                 \
                                errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), FrmVar, _TRUNCATE);                     \
                                    if (errno == STRUNCATE)                                                     \
                                        fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", FrmVar, ToVar);  \
                            } while(0);

//  clear numeric array macro
#define ClrNumArr(ArrNam, ArrCnt)           \
            for (s = 0; s < ArrCnt; s++)    \
                ArrNam[s] = 0;


uint32_t    s;          //  subscript

typedef struct {
    short   C;
    short   YY;
    short   MM;
    short   DD;
} SysDat;
```

**TstMacCmpErr:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TstBasInc.h"      //  test basic include file

#define ARRCNT 3

int main()
{
    char    Cnd = 'E';      //  define to use 'else' path
    char    ToVar[7 + 1];   //  Cpy To-Variable
    int     IntArr[ARRCNT]; //  integer array

    Cpy(ToVar, "short")                     //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
    if (Cnd != 'E')
//      Cpy(ToVar, "short string");         //  won't compile:  illegal else without matching if
        Cpy(ToVar, "short string")          //  will compile
    else
        Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");    //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
//  the following code shows how I thought the macro would expand to    
    {                                                                                   \
        errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), "short str", _TRUNCATE);                \
        if (errno == STRUNCATE)                                                         \
            fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short str", ToVar);;    \
    }

    if (Cnd == 'E') {
        ClrNumArr(IntArr, ARRCNT)               //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
            printf("intarr[0] = %d\n", IntArr[0]);
    }
    else
        printf("intarr[0] is garbage\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The results follow:

```
string 'extra long string' was truncated to 'extra l'
string 'short str' was truncated to 'short s'
intarr[0] = 0;
```

As the comments say, when I have a semi-colon after `Cpy(ToVar, "short string");` it won't even compile because I get an `"C2181   illegal else without matching if"` error.  As you see, I tried adding a do-while in the macro as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros), but it didn't make any difference.  When the macro code is copied directly (even without the do-while) that code works okay.  I would have thought just adding the braces in the macro would have fixed the problem but it didn't.  It must have something to do with the `Cpy` ending in an `if` because the `ClrNumArr` macro compiles with or without the semi-colon.  So can someone tell me why the `Cpy` macro doesn't just replace the text?  I must be missing something simple.

I'm using VS 2015 Community Edition Update 1.

Edit:  I documented the problem and isolated it to (I think) the `if` statement in the `Cpy` macro.  *Still* nobody has explained why the macro didn't expand the way I thought it should.  That should have been the title of the post, as that's my question more than the problem with the semi-colon, which I now have a solution for.

Comment: Don't put semi colons in macro definitions.

Comment: Don't use macros where a function would work.

Comment: @iharob:  Thank you.  In Visual Studio, I get `C2143  syntax error: Missing ';' before 'if'` and the same message on many other lines.

Comment: see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html note that semicolon is actually a null statement

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe:  I thought about that, but I thought the overhead calling a function would slow things down.  I could be calling this simple routine perhaps millions of times if in loops, is why I left it a macro.

Comment: @tigris:  that's why I added a do-while in the macro, but it didn't' make any difference.

Comment: 0) As stated, don't use macros where a functions also works. One reason just bit you. 1) Do not try premature optimisations. The compiler and CPU are possibly smarter than you are. 2) If your code really **proves** too slow, use `inline` functions and/or link time optimisation (LTO). 3) As a beginner don't even think about such things.

Comment: @Olaf:  All your points are probably valid.  I did some profiling of calling an empty procedure, but I lost it.  It maybe wasn't as significant as I thought.  I would like to learn what an `inline` function is and LTO, but I think that's a little too advanced for me right now.

Comment: Hmm... simply adding `inline` specifier is too advanced, but macros are not? Strange priorities, I'd say. Note that  as I wrote - the error would not have occured with either a normal or an `inline` function. About LTO, I basically agree; I just mentioned it for completeness. Until then, don't try replacing functions with macros. (Personal note: I personally think a student using such a macro should fail it's assignment/test/whatever. Regardless of the rest of the code. I strongly emphasise that in my lessons.)

Comment: @Olaf:  In my reading, I've never ran across `inline`.  Granted I've only read K&R and 3 other books.  I've seen `inline` on SO, but never grokked what it meant.  As far as the macro itself, I don't see why it should cause me to fail a test.  Seems pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: Don't use K&R. This does not even cover C99, not to mention standard C (which is C11 - there is no other valid C standard). You would not want to learn driving/using a Model-T car either, or a pre-digital mobile phone.

Comment: I admit, I've heard that about K&R and there only being the C11 standard, but I had to start somewhere.  :)

Comment: On further investigation, it's proved that the macro is only a few milliseconds faster than a function call, over 1,000,000 loops.  So I will change it to a function.  However, nobody has yet explained _why_ the macro didn't expand the way I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to Sourav's answer, you asked why this works as a macro body:

```
{ 
    errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), "short str", _TRUNCATE); 
    if (errno == STRUNCATE) 
        fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short str", ToVar);; 
}
```

That's because in your context, it evaluates to this:

```
if (Cnd != 'E')
{ 
    errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), "short str", _TRUNCATE); 
    if (errno == STRUNCATE) 
        fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short str", ToVar);; 
}
else
    Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");    //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
```

The `if` part of the block, which previously was a single statement is now a block.  So now the `else` is properly matched.

That's still not a good way to implement a macro, however.  Then including the semicolon (which users of a macro would generally expect to work) would cause an error.

```
if (Cnd != 'E')
    Cpy(ToVar, "short string");     // invalid syntax
else
    Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");
```

You keep saying "why didn't the macro expand the way I thought it would".  It **is** expanding as you thought it would.  Based on your original definition, this:

```
if (Cnd != 'E')
    Cpy(ToVar, "short string");
else
    Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");    //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
```

Expands to this:

```
if (Cnd != 'E')
    do{
        errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), "short string", _TRUNCATE);
        if (errno == STRUNCATE)
            fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short string", ToVar);
    } while(0);;
else
    Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");    //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
```

The first semicolon after the `while(0)` (which is part of the macro) ends the first part of the `if` statement.  The second semicolon (not part of the macro) is another (empty) statement.  This statement is considered to be outside of the `if` statement.  Because of this, the `else` is misplaced.

You would get the same error if you had something like this:

```
if (Cnd != 'E')
    do{
        errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), "short string", _TRUNCATE);
        if (errno == STRUNCATE)
            fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short string", ToVar);
    } while(0);
fprintf(stderr, "this is outside of the if statement\n");
else
    Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");    //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
```

Note that I indented the `fprintf` call to where is logically belongs.  That's exactly where the empty statement (i.e. the extra semicolon) belongs as well.

Comment: Ah...  Thank you.  I see now where you expanded the macro to say `} while(0);;`.  When I was expanding the macro in my head, I was putting the extra semi-colon after the `printf` instead of the `while`.  This also explains why skyking's answer worked.

Answer (score 3):

In case you put a semicolon,

```
    Cpy(ToVar, "short")                     //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
    if (Cnd != 'E')
//      Cpy(ToVar, "short string");         //  won't compile:  illegal else without matching if
        Cpy(ToVar, "short string")          //  will compile
    else
        Cpy(ToVar, "extra long string");    //  compiles with or without the semi-colon
```

this makes the syntax look like

```
if (...)
    ...;
    ;                // <-- The problem here
else
   ...;
```

which is illegal syntax, as the `else` will have no associated `if` in this syntax.

OTOH, in case you write

```
if (...) {
    ...;
    ;                // <-- no problem here, inside a block
 }
else
   ...;
```

the `else` is associated with the previous `if`. So, all fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I had already found that if I enclosed the macro in braces, it would work fine.  That's why I added the braces in the macro, so I wouldn't have to keep typing in the extra braces every time I wanted to use the macro inside an `if`.  My question is why don't the braces in the macro expand properly.

Comment: @J.Toran I think you did not get the point of my post. The macro definition is one _statement_, and without the `{}` in the code, the ending `;` present the code will break the `if..else` coalition. It does not matter whether you a `{}` in the MACRO definition or not. Am I clear?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  But why does the following code work:  ` {                     \
  errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), "short str", _TRUNCATE);    \
  if (errno == STRUNCATE)               \
   fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short str", ToVar);; \
 }`  and the macro doesn't expande to this code?

Comment: Thank you.  I did not get the point of your post until I read the post of dbush.  You and the others deserve credit for a correct answer but I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem becomes obvious if you look at what happens at expansion. The macro already expans to a statement including trailing semicolon.

The problem becomes apparent if you're using it together with an `if`-`else` construct since if you append an extra semicolon it would expand into two statements.

For example if you do the following:

```
#define HELLO printf("Hello\n");
```

and then

```
if( some_condition )
    HELLO;
else
    something_else();
```

this would expand to

```
if( some_condition )
    printf("Hello\n");;
else
    something_else();
```

and you see that there's two statements between the `if` and `else` which means that the `else` becomes out of place.

The very reason of using the `do` - `while(0)` is to create something that would fit where one statement is to be fitted and then it's imperative that you leave out the trailing semicolon after the `while(0)`. That is your define should look like this instead:

```
#define Cpy(ToVar, FrmVar) do   {                                                                                 \
                            errno = strncpy_s(ToVar, sizeof(ToVar), FrmVar, _TRUNCATE);                     \
                                if (errno == STRUNCATE)                                                     \
                                    fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", FrmVar, ToVar);  \
                        } while(0)
```

Comment: Thank you.  But why don't the braces expand along with the other lines to `do { strncpy(etc) if (condition) printf(line) } while (0);;`?  Isn't the last "`;`" just a no-op?  Or not?

Comment: Yes, the last semicolon is what's called an empty statement. It count's as a statement in it's own right when parsing the source.

Comment: When I added a `;` at the end of the section where I copied the macro code, as in: `fprintf(stderr, "string '%s' was truncated to '%s'\n", "short str", ToVar);;` with 2 semi-colons, it compiled and ran okay.  My question is why didn't the macro expand with the braces and the do-while?

Comment: Thank you for the addition to your answer.  When I left the `;` off the while, and added it after the "call" to the macro, it compiled and ran okay.  But I'm still not sure _why_ the macro didn't expand as I showed in my question.  The code I copied directly from the macro worked okay.  The extra section seems to be identical to what I thought the macro would expand to.  (If you see what I mean.)

Comment: Thank you.  I did not understand that the macro wasn't expanding like i thought it was until I read the post of dbush.  You also deserve credit for helping me understand.